# Is there any alternate feature available for java reflection in java 6/7/8?

Tags: java

To invoke method dynamically is there any other feature available in java 6/7/8 other than java reflection?

Also, is there any improvement in java reflection in java 7/8?.

Below is my current code using reflection but I need to implement my business logic without reflection.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Core core = new Core();
        Map<Object, Object> obj = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
        core.create(obj);
    }

    public Map create(Map<Object, Object> obj) {

        // TODO implement core business logic
        System.out.println("Core Business Logic Completed");
        try {
            obj = invokeAfter(obj);
        } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public Map invokeAfter(Map<Object, Object> obj) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException,
            IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        Class params[] = {};
        // TODO below list will be injected using spring configuration in
        // configurable approach
        List<String> afterClassNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        afterClassNameList.add("Custom11");
        afterClassNameList.add("Custom22");

        if (!afterClassNameList.isEmpty()) {
            for (String className : afterClassNameList) {
                System.out.println("Class Name::" + className);
                Class thisClass = Class.forName(className);
                Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
                Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod("create", params);
                obj = (Map<Object, Object>) thisMethod.invoke(iClass, obj);
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}



  public class Custom1 {
    public Map create(Map<Object, Object> obj) {
        // TODO implement custom business logic
        return obj;
    }
}



   public class Custom2 {
    public Map create(Map<Object, Object> obj) {
        // TODO implement custom business logic
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need to implement my business logic without reflection" - may we ask why? There is a tool that is meant for things like that, why not use it?

Comment: I'm trying to guess what your business logic is. Typically I use the alternate technique "method call", especially for implementing business logic. What is it that keeps you from doing so?

Comment: Where does your business logic come from? External jar files?

Comment: If classes supposed to have the method, why not add an interface with that method, and document properly what it's supposed to do? There is indeed a method superior to reflection in Java, it's called class polymorhism - clean, documentable, able to be optimized during JIT compilation.

Comment: @rvit34 & Olaf Kock : I am trying to develop kind of reusable code (core). I have few scenarios where some additional custom code need to developed in separate module (kind of external jar) but it should be invoked immediately after my core business logic executed in configurable way. This is what my code does using reflection.

Comment: Generally you use reflection-like tools when your code can have absolutely no idea what shape the objects it has to deal with are, for example in an ORM or a dependency injection library. In most other cases, even if you use `Class.forName().newInstance()` to dynamically load and instantiate a class, you don't then continue to call methods using reflection. Also, if you've got Spring (as it seems from one of the comments in the code), use it. It's got all this built into it.

Comment: And another, subjective word of advice: don't try to develop reusable code. Develop simple code that works well. More often than not you'll find it's a lot easier to re-use than code that was "designed" for re-use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much better option is to use an interface which your implementations implement.

```
interface Builder<T> {
   T create(Map<?, ?> properties;
}

class Custom1 implements Builder<Map> {
```

You can use byte code generation, instrumentation or runtime compilation, but these are more complex than using reflection.

If you were using Java 8 you could use `Function<Map, Map>` as an existing interface.

Comment: I am trying to develop kind of reusable code (core). I have few scenarios where some additional custom code need to developed in separate module (kind of external jar) but it should be invoked immediately after my core business logic executed in configurable way.

Comment: Particularly as – judging from one of the comments – Spring will be involved. And this is exactly the sort of stuff Spring was invented for. Create an interface, and let Spring load the different implementations dynamically.

Comment: As Peter suggested, you probably should declare some interfaces part in your core. In additional modules just implement these interfaces. If Core knows about them only in run-time use reflection|DI to load the modules.